# ST_Transform not working locally

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.6, postgis-2.4

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 and PostGIS extension 2.4.4. On my machine, I get an error while running ST_Transform query:

```
SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('27.9252', '-26.0987'),4326),32619)
```

returns

```
transform: couldn't project point (27.9252 -26.0987 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)
```

But when I run it on our testing/prod environment hosted in AWS, I don't get the error message and it suceeds with result

```
POINT (9591132.411356987 -11522592.397666786)
```

Locally, I am using Mint 18.3 and it is configured in French.

I could not figure out configuration difference between my local environment and our hosted environment.

How can I get this query to be run without error ?

`SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version()` returns:

- Locally

  `POSTGIS="2.4.4 r16526" PGSQL="96" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" TOPOLOGY RASTER`
- Hosted environment

  `POSTGIS="2.4.4 r16526" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.4, released 2017/06/23" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.12" RASTER`

Comment: Can you post the result of SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();  for both environments?

Comment: Also, trying remote the quotes '' around your coordinates. ST_MakePoint takes double and not strings as input. Although it seems to create the point anyway...

Comment: Try with this `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(27.9252, -26.0987),4326),32619))` The result should be `POINT(9591132.41135699 -11522592.3976668)`.

Comment: @GobTron edited the question with results

Comment: @user30184 not working neither. Actually I try to understand the configuration difference between our hosted environment and my local installation

Comment: You are lucky to get an error in at least one of the environment. [EPSG 32619](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-19n/) is UTM zone 19, whose bounds are between -66 and -72 degrees of longitude. A coordinate around 27 degrees is way too far and its "conversion" to UTM 19 is therefore pointless.

Comment: @JGH That's what I thought. Yet, my colleague has the same result on his machine as in hosted env

Comment: @iguanito could you check on your colleagues *PROJ* version; there was a change for UTM to the *Extended Transverse Mercator* between versions 4.9.2 and 4.9.3. not sure though if that is the actual reason (e.g. one projection allows for out-of-zone coordinates, the other doesn't). the underlying *proj4* is a likely culprit for an error while transforming.

Comment: @ThingumaBob you were right, upgrading PROJ fixed the issue. Even if I don't know exactly what the issue was, and not even if the query is valid, I have now my local environment closer to test/prod. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An upgrade to PROJ 4.9.3 fixes the issue:

- downloaded manually libproj12.deb which contains PROJ 4.9.3
- installed deb and created symlink manually `ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.12.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.9`
- restart PostgreSQL